# Answering old questions without answers

Tags: discussion, questions

Would it be considered bad form to answer an old question that doesn't have an answer?

For example say I have an answer to this question:

> Why doesn't this output true when I type blue?
>
> ```
> def question
>   print "What's the color of the sky?"
>   input = gets.chomp
>   if input = blue
>     puts "Yes"
>   else
>     puts "wrong"
>   end
> end
> ```

Lets say this question is over 8 months old, and has no answer. Would answering it be a bad thing, or a good thing?

Comment: Be careful - questions without answers are very suspicious:)

Comment: @MartinJames That made my day

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> would answering it be a bad thing, or a good thing..?

It would be a **good** thing.

Absolutely.

A better thing would be to find an answered duplicate and close it as such a duplicate. If it isn't one, answer it.

Comment: Don't forget those badges you get: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer and https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival

Comment: Awesome thank you. I'll accept this when I get a chance

Answer (score 6):

It would be a good thing to answer old questions because people come searching answers/solutions for similar issues later on as well. This happens with generic questions in widely used technology areas.

However, for specific problems like the one you mentioned I am not so sure as it is not something many people would commonly ask.

Comment: It was just an example.